# Visual studio 2015 Update 3 - I cannot create new web applications. Nuget issue maybe?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I've been working on an existing project for a while so I'm not sure when this problem started, but when I do "New Project" and pick asp.net 4.5 (or 4.5.1 or 4.6 or 4.6.1) and web application, then any type of project (except empty application) then I get an error box as the project first opens up with missing reference to a dll.  If I open up the references folder then there are LOADS of yellow triangles on Antlr3.Runtim, EntityFramework, Identity.Core, you name it...

Doesn't seem to be a permissions thing from what I can tell but I'm completely stumped - I cannot now create even a simple web forms project if I want to.

Comment: I tried deleting nuget package manager for vs2015 so I could reinstall. When I install it fails: `Install Error : System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Compression, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Currently "repairing" my VS install to see if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

It was unrelated to MS Visual Studio. It appears that something had corrupted my .net.  I uninstalled .net 4.5 and 4.7 and re-ran installation after a reboot.  That cured the problem.